# How to insert multiple numbers into table in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Word</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">

<?php
include("connect.php");
mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES UTF8");


$select="SELECT * FROM students_info WHERE  bash='A'";

$result=mysqli_query($link,$select) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo $row['Name']."<input type='text' name='warzy1'>"."<br>";
} 

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">

</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
include("connect.php");
mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES UTF8");

$warzy1=@$_POST['warzy1'];
$warz=implode(",",(array)$warzy1);

$insert="INSERT INTO word (Warzy_Yakam) VALUES ('$warz')";

mysqli_query($link,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($link));

?>
```

I have one table in the database in PHP MySQL and some input filed with name students how i can insert multiple data to each students at the same time?appear in the image

[image]

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set names for inputs based on students ids and be array

```
echo $row['Name']."<input type='text' name='st_{$row['id']}[]'>"."<br>";
```

then, on submit you can get studen id form POST data

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos($k, 'st_') !== false) {
        $studen_id = (int)str_replace('st_', '', $k);
        foreach ($v as $student_data_item) {
             // save it
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `mysqli_*` functions everywhere (see `mysql_error`).

Then you need to make the name of the input field an array. After that loop over the posted array like this:

```
include("connect.php");
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES UTF8");

$select = "SELECT * FROM students_info WHERE  bash='A'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $select) or die(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Name']."<input type='text' name='warzy1[]'>"."<br>";
}

?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php
include("connect.php");
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES UTF8");

if (!empty($_POST['warzy1'])) {
    $warzy1 = $_POST['warzy1'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO word (Warzy_Yakam) VALUES (?)");

    foreach ($warzy1 as $w) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $w);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you colburton, I use your code but not working to send data, data don't send to the database :( .

Comment: appear this warning(Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in E:\wamp\www\Projefct Exam Result(2018)\word.php on line 34)